# Angular 2 RC 1 IE9 Unable to get property 'contains' of undefined or null reference

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, angular

I am using the following with angular 2:

```
node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.min.js
node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js
node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js
node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js
node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js
```

Works in all other browsers except IE 9.

Anyone seeing this error?

Comment: Seeing as that angular 2 just went to RC, I'd say open an issue on GitHub.

Comment: I have seen this error in IE10. Still not sure how to resolve it yet though.